# How to load data from REST api every x seconds and update UI without flickering in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, zone

I have an angular application where I periodically want to fetch data from my backend and show the updates in the UI. This is my backend service :

```
  // _backendService
  apiDashboardJobs(): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpClient.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/dashboard/jobs`);
  }
```

My component code:

```
      this.jobsOverview$ = interval(3000)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        switchMap(response => this._backendService.apiDashboardJobs()),
        map(response => 
          [
            {'status' :'Completed', 'number': response.completed, 'color': 'rgb(94,210,86)'},
            //...
          ]
        ));

    public trackByFn(index, item) {
      return index;
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      // Unsubscribe and complete the destroy$ subject
      this.destroy$.next();
      this.destroy$.complete();
    }
```

My html code:

```
                  <tr *ngFor="let job of jobsOverview$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn" style="height: 30px;">
                    <td>
                      <div style.background-color="{{job.color}}"> </div> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {{job.status}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {{job.number}}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

Now, this code seemed to work fine initially, but after some time the table does not render at all anymore and I see a bunch of these errors in the network tab:
[image: chrome network tab]

Can someone guide me on how to fix this?

Comment: Well if it's working fine at begining then I think the issue is more related to your server or directly your backend.
There are probably some rate limiting which prevent the next requests to be treated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with [Gilles's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77049868/how-to-load-data-from-rest-api-every-x-seconds-and-update-ui-without-flickering#comment135830179_77049868)

> Well if it's working fine at begining then I think the issue is more related to your server or directly your backend. There are probably some rate limiting which prevent the next requests to be treated

The screenshot shows that the requests are **cancelled**. Cancellation is done **client side**.

Looking at your code, you're using an interval (every 3s) and a switchMap. Meaning that if your server for any reason takes longer than 3s to reply, the next tick of your `interval` will happen and `switchMap` will cancel the ongoing request.

If you replace your `switchMap` with an `exhaustMap`, it should work as expected.

EDIT:

Also note that in order to avoid that back pressure in the first place, you could improve the code to:

- Start the first request straight away. In the current state, it waits 3s the first time which is time lost for the user
- Handle gracefully errors and keep retrying
- Call again your backend 3s **after the previous call is done**. Which is a lot different than every 3s as it takes into account the fact that the server could take some time to reply

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
defer(() => this._backendService.apiDashboardJobs())
  .pipe(retry({ delay: 3000 }), repeat({ delay: 3000 }))
  .subscribe(() => console.log('Received answer'));
```

Here's a live demo where I also show that errors are handled as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uah45e?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: Perfect, this works for me! Thank you. One thing that I noticed also, is that I can not set the updateInterval as a field if I use this code in ngOnInit() as it will be undefined. This seemed to be the reason why my interval went off too often. 

So this was the main reason it didn't work:

private _updateInterval = 3000;

ngOnInit(): void {
 // my code...
}

I didn't show this in my question to improve readability.

Comment: Well my bad I didn't pay attention to the request status. Good catch @maxime1992

Comment: No worries @Gilles. Happens to the best of us :). markai, I've edited my answer to remove backpressure and have a more elegant solution, please take another look

Comment: @maxime1992 that works too. I assigned the response in the subscribe function to my jobsOverview.
.subscribe(response => {
        this.jobsOverview = [
            {'status' :'Completed', 'number': response.completed, 'color': 'rgb(94,210,86)'},
// ...
]
//...
and changed jobsOverview$: Observable<any[]> to jobsOverview: any[]. Seems like an elegant solution. Many thanks.